# Conditional Sort Expression in Python for Plone

Tags: python, sorting, plone

I am working on a custom view for a folder-type content object that pulls in multiple levels of content (a manual that contains chapters that contains sections that contains documents). Each custom content object have their own respective number fields (chapternumber; sectionnumber; docnumber). I am able to create a view at the manual level to pull in all the content and display the respective content object number.

I want to be able to sort my content objects (in order) by chapternumber; if not then by sectionnumber; if not then by docnumber; if not then by sortable_title. Below is the TAL statement I am using to sort by chapter number only (the below code snippet works to sort content by chapter number but does not display content that does not have a chapter number - thus the reason I want to sort by multiple conditions):

```
<tal:foldercontents define="
        custom_sort python:{'sort_on': 'chapternumber', 'sort_order': 'ascending'};
        contentFilter contentFilter|request/contentFilter|custom_sort;
        ...
```

My custom view is based on the code from the folder standard view template in: Products.CMFPlone-4.3.2/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/folder_listing.pt

```
<tal:foldercontents define="
        contentFilter contentFilter|request/contentFilter|nothing;
        contentFilter python:contentFilter and dict(contentFilter) or {};
        limit_display limit_display|request/limit_display|nothing;
        limit_display python:limit_display and int(limit_display) or None;
        more_url more_url|request/more_url|string:folder_contents;
        is_a_topic python:context.portal_type=='Topic';
        folderContents folderContents|nothing; folderContents python:folderContents or is_a_topic and context.queryCatalog(batch=True, **contentFilter) or context.getFolderContents(contentFilter, batch=True, b_size=limit_display or 9999);
        site_properties context/portal_properties/site_properties;
        use_view_action site_properties/typesUseViewActionInListings|python:();
        Batch python:modules['Products.CMFPlone'].Batch;
        b_start python:request.get('b_start', 0);
        batch python:isinstance(folderContents, Batch) and folderContents or Batch(folderContents, limit_display or 9999, int(b_start), orphan=1);
        isAnon context/@@plone_portal_state/anonymous;
        normalizeString nocall: context/plone_utils/normalizeString;
        toLocalizedTime nocall: context/@@plone/toLocalizedTime;
        show_about python:not isAnon or site_properties.allowAnonymousViewAbout;
        navigation_root_url context/@@plone_portal_state/navigation_root_url;
        pas_member context/@@pas_member;
        plone_view context/@@plone;">

<tal:listing condition="batch">

...
```

First, is it possible to sort by multiple conditions for a custom view template? If so, how would I implement that? If not, is there a way to implement what I am trying to do?

Comment: How do you want to compare an object that has no chapter number with one that has no section number? Is a document with no chapter number to acquire the chapter number from its parent?

Comment: this is the tricky part. the structure of the site is: i have a manual content object that is folderish. a chapter content object that is folderish. a session content object that is folderish (customer wants a manual that contains chapters that contains sections that contains documents.) sometime chapters will contain documents (without sections). sometimes the manual will contain documents (without chapters or sections). and yes, sometimes there will be no object numbers - thus why i will need to sort by title if no number is present.

Comment: and steve - to answer your question (which i realize i did not do) is no. a document without a number should not acquire the parents number. it shall remain unnumbered.

Comment: (continued)... there is a chapternumber, sectionnumber and docnumber field with each type. they are also added to the catalog index as a fieldindex so i can globally call and sort on them. i am able to modify the folder standard view to display three levels of content on the page (manual > chapter > section > document) and want to sort by their respective number - or by title if no number is present. old example is [here](http://www.healthsystem.virginia.edu/docs/manuals/policies/mc) and the new version not working is [here](http://www.healthsystem.virginia.edu/newdocs/manuals/policies/mc)

Comment: Is that a single fieldindex? If so, can you append the sortable title to the end of it?

Comment: i have 'chapternumber', 'sectionnumber' and 'docnumber' registered as a fieldindex. when you say "append the sortable title" are you inferring to merge the sortable title to the number field value? (if number is "0001" then after merge the number would be "0001 document title" or something else? - just so i am on the same page)

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade (pin) your Products.ZCatalog version to 3.0+.
From 3.0alpha multiple sort has been added.

This is what you can from CHANGES:

> Added support for sort_on queries with any number of sort indexes and differing sort_order values. For example: {‘foo’: ‘a’, ‘sort_on’: (‘foo’, ‘bar’)} {‘foo’: ‘a’, ‘sort_on’: (‘foo’, ‘bar’), ‘sort_order’: (”, ‘reverse’)} {‘foo’: ‘a’, ‘sort_on’: (‘foo’, ‘bar’, ‘baz’)}

Comment: Nice, did not know that!!

Comment: @Mathias yeah, a problem of Zope. Unluckily is a really hidden feature. Also the new `not` query is great and works well.

Comment: @rodfersou the `not` query is here

Comment: so far i have not been able to get the example working - yet. i am using this snippet: tap:define="custom_sort python:{'sort_on': ('chapternumber', 'sectionnumber', 'docnumber', 'sortable_title'), 'sort_order': ('ascending')};"

Comment: Think that 'sort_order': ('ascending') is the default (so you cans skip it). Before trying to dig into contentFilter usage, try to manually run the search from a ZMI Python script, or from a python pdb or from the debug instance. This to be sure that the problem is not in the way to are buildout the dict.
Again: are you sure that you have all index correctly created and indesed? Are they FieldIndex or KeywordIndex ?